# mysqli, prepared statements, and INSERT-SELECTs

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

Let's pretend that I have two tables in an **InnoDB** database: `categories` and `jokes`; and that I'm using **PHP/MySQLi** to do the work. The tables look like so:

```
CATEGORIES
id (int, primary, auto_inc)  |  category_name (varchar[64])
============================================================
1                               knock, knock

JOKES
id (int, primary, auto_inc)  |  category_id (int)  | joke_text (varchar[255])
=============================================================================
empty
```

Thanks to a [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18151546/innodb-only-insert-record-if-referenced-id-exists-without-foreign-keys/18153952#18153952) answer on here, I discovered that you could do the following in order to add a new joke comprised of: `$joke_text`, `$category_id`.

```
INSERT INTO jokes (category_id, joke_text)
SELECT c.id, '$joke_text'
FROM categories AS c WHERE c.id = $category_id;
```

This enables me, without the use of foreign keys, to be sure that the `$category_id` value refers to an existing category (*please ignore the issue of foreign keys, as my question is aimed at helping me learn "complicated" prepared statements*).

So that worked just fine. However, I am now trying to learn prepared statements and, after spending all day on it, I finally have the basics down. Unfortunately, I have **ABSOLUTELY NO IDEA** how to to execute the above SQL query with prepared statements, under mysqli, and I have not been able to find any info online regarding such an issue.

If anyone can help me out, I'd be very appreciative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you create the statement very much like a normal statement you have made

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO jokes (category_id, joke_text)
SELECT c.id, ?
FROM categories AS c WHERE c.id = ?;");
```

Get the statement bound to the parameter 's' stands for string data and i for integer

```
$stmt->bind_param('si', $joke_text,$category_id);   // bind to the parameters
```

/* execute prepared statement */

```
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Isn't escaping the POST data with the mysqli real_escape_string function defeating the purpose of using prepared statements? You use prepared statements to skip that step. Else you it would be like calling the addslashes function and then escaping it with the real_escape_string function. Or that's at least what I read when first using MySQLi before moving to PDO. See [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232084/is-mysql-real-escape-string-necessary-when-using-prepared-statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232084/is-mysql-real-escape-string-necessary-when-using-prepared-statements)

Comment: I agree, its just a habit :) that can be removed safely

Comment: Double escaping might end up giving you two single quotes when one was sent. That's where I see the problem of the security. It's best we advise that the habit is removed. :)

Comment: Hmm, perhaps this seemed a lot more complicated than it actually was. However, wouldn't I also want to put a `?` for the `WHERE c.id = $category_id` statement? So it would be: `WHERE c.id = ?`, and then I'd just add `$category_id` as a second param on `stmt->bind_param`?

Comment: Not necessary, you want to do that only with parameters being added from external sources, this is getting data from db

Comment: But `$category_id` is from the user, not from the db. Is it not possible to get a MySQL injection from it?

Comment: My personal opinion is to use the <pre>WHERE c.id = ?</pre> and then bind it since it's a variable. I guess I just don't like to take chances. **Edit:** Since it's a variable, the I suppose you bind it.

Comment: Edited, sorry about ignoring it as from db

Answer (score -1):

I was actually writing some code but I realised that you were searching online for this too. So instead I got you the link to the PHP website where you can see many of these.

[Prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

[mysqli in general](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Since you are learning MySQLi, why not just move to PDO instead. It's very similar but I think that's where the future of this is headed.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers