# How to use both SELECT and INSERT query on single php prepared statement?

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I am trying to insert a record and get the id of that record using a prepared statement. For that, I write a query `"INSERT INTO ". $natureFlight ."(typeFlight, dateTimeSubmit, emb, acType, reg, companyName, callSign, dateFlight) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?); SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();"` which works fine in MySQL console but doesn't work using a prepared statement. If I remove the `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();` from the query then it can insert record using a prepared statement.

I search for the solution and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18393635/mysqli-prepared-statements-and-insert-selects) but does not work for me.

Here is a code

```
$natureFlight = $_POST['selectedNatureFlight'];
$typeFlight = $_POST['selectedTypeFlight'];
$dateTimeSubmit = $_POST['dateTime'];
$emb = $_POST['emb'];
$acType = $_POST['acType'];
$reg = $_POST['reg'];
$companyName = $_POST['companyName'];
$callSign = $_POST['callSign'];
$dateFlight = $_POST['dateFlight'];

$insertRecord = "INSERT INTO ". $natureFlight ."(`typeFlight`, `dateTimeSubmit`, `emb`, `acType`, `reg`, `companyName`, `callSign`, `dateFlight`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?); SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($insertRecord);
$stmt->bind_param("ssssssss", $typeFlight, $dateTimeSubmit, $emb, $acType, $reg, $companyName, $callSign, $dateFlight);
if($stmt->execute()){
    $stmt->bind_result($id);
    while($stmt->fetch()) {
         echo $id;
        }           
} else{
    $res['error'] = true;
    $res['message'] = $stmt->error;
}
```

After I run this I get an error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on bool in
D:\xampp\htdocs\test\proc\flightPDF\src\body\user\records.php:40 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in 
D:\xampp\htdocs\test\proc\flightPDF\src\body\user\records.php on line 40
```

Line 40 contain `$stmt->bind_param("ssssssss", $typeFlight, $dateTimeSubmit, $emb, $acType, $reg, $companyName, $callSign, $dateFlight);`

Comment: If you insert record in PHP, you can get last insert id with $conn->lastInsertId() atfer execute. Don't need query last id query string. Please remove it in your query string.

Comment: @AuNguyen ok I will try this

Comment: after using $conn->lastInsertId(), i am getting error `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli::lastInsertId()`

Comment: Don’t know about how reliable last insert id is in MySQL, but it is buggy in other databases. Best solution I’ve found is to select by the same thing you inserted, ordered by id desc. It’s not foolproof; you have to consider what are the chances another insert with the same information could occur in between your insert and select... (yeah, I’m not too worried)

Comment: Please provide script code for create your $conn. Do you use mysqli or PDO to connect mysql? PDO: $conn->lastInsertId() , mysqli: $conn->insert_id

Comment: @AuNguyen I am using PHP prepared statement

Comment: @TimMorton ok, this is also a good solution, I will try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't prepare multiple statements. That is why your prepare is failing and `$stmt` is a boolean (false). To fix it, remove the `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` from your `INSERT` query and change the code to this, using [`insert_id`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) to get the last insert id:

```
$insertRecord = "INSERT INTO ". $natureFlight ."(`typeFlight`, `dateTimeSubmit`, `emb`, `acType`, `reg`, `companyName`, `callSign`, `dateFlight`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($insertRecord);
$stmt->bind_param("ssssssss", $typeFlight, $dateTimeSubmit, $emb, $acType, $reg, $companyName, $callSign, $dateFlight);
if (!$stmt) {
    $res['error'] = true;
    $res['message'] = $conn->error;
}
elseif ($stmt->execute()) {
    echo $conn->insert_id;
} 
else {
    $res['error'] = true;
    $res['message'] = $stmt->error;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use lastInsertId Instead Of SELECT Statement

```
$last_id = $conn->lastInsertId;
```

Hope this will help you..!!

Comment: I am getting error `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli::lastInsertId()`

Comment: @Meet_Soni I am using PHP prepared statement

Comment: @Nawaraj if you getting this kind of error then use $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn); and let me know about same. May be it works.

Comment: it does not block the execution but also does not catch the last id

Comment: Remove this SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() and put this 
if($stmt->execute()){
echo $conn->insert_id;
}

and check same.